# CASE expressions on datetime columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to access a datetime column to find out whether the date is within a week from today, or overdue. Then write a new column's value to say `Incoming`, `Overdue` or `Fine`.

```
SELECT
CASE next_action_date
WHEN (BETWEEN GETDATE()+7 AND GETDATE()) THEN 'Incoming'
WHEN (< GETDATE()) THEN 'Overdue'
ELSE 'Fine'
END AS condition
FROM
tableName
```

This is what I've got so far, but as you can probably see by looking, it doesn't work at all:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'.

Comment: Strongly recommend avoiding lazy shorthand like `GETDATE()+7`. This syntax doesn't work for the newer types like `DATE` and `DATETIME2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try

```
select CASE 
    when next_action_date between GETDATE() and GETDATE()+7 then 'Incoming'
    when next_action_date < GETDATE() THEN 'Overdue'
    else 'fine' end as Condition
from(
    select GETDATE()+6 next_action_date
)x
```

Comment: Little bit of changing around, but it worked in the end. Thanks very much. Ended up with

Comment: select
CASE 
when next_action_date between GETDATE() and GETDATE()+7 then 'Incoming'
when proj_actions_next_action_date < GETDATE() THEN 'Overdue'
else 'fine' end
from tableName

Answer (score 5):

There are [two syntaxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173318.aspx) of the `CASE` expression - the so-called *simple* one that compares a single value against a list of other values, and a *searched* one with generic boolean conditions. You picked the simple case, but it does not have enough flexibility for what you need; you should switch to the searched syntax, like this:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN next_action_date BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE()+7 THEN 'Incoming'
    WHEN next_action_date < GETDATE() THEN 'Overdue'
    ELSE 'Fine'
END AS condition
FROM
tableName
```

Comment: Pretty much the same thing I ended up with.
Cheers very much :)

Comment: +1 but pedantic semantics: `CASE` is an expression, not a statement. Those semantics often lead people to believe it can be used for control of flow etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You're right, `case` is a statement in many other languages, but in SQL it's an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME
SELECT @Date = GETDATE()

SELECT
    condition = CASE 
        WHEN t.next_action_date BETWEEN @Date AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, @Date) THEN 'Incoming'
        WHEN t.next_action_date < @Date THEN 'Overdue'
        ELSE 'Fine'
    END 
FROM dbo.tableName t
```

Answer (score 1):

use `DATEADD(Day, 7, GETDATE())`

Answer (score 0):

You should uses the other form of the case statement

```
    SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN (next_action_date BETWEEN GETDATE()+7 AND GETDATE()) THEN 'Incoming'
        WHEN (next_action_date < GETDATE()) THEN 'Overdue'
        ELSE 'Fine'
    END AS condition
    FROM
    tableName
```

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15633